# timeit on separate cells different to a combined cell

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook, timeit, segments

I was performing some code timing of cells in jupyter notebook where I was writing to segments of a numpy array and found that breaking up the code produces a different processing time, compared to original combined code.

The folowing is a minimal example code.
First setting up some values:

```
import numpy as np
V=10000
K=1000
zrs=np.random.random(V)
```

Then timing full code:

```
%%timeit
a=np.zeros(V*K)
for n in range(0,K):
    a[n*V:(n+1)*V]=zrs
```

this returns:
*45.6 ms ± 2.82 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)*

However, if I run the code in separate cells, I get:

```
%%timeit
a=np.zeros(V*K)
```

*307 µs ± 2.33 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)*

and, first declaring 'a':

```
a=np.zeros(V*K)
```

then running timeit on the second part of the code:

```
%%timeit
for n in range(0,K):
    a[n*V:(n+1)*V]=zrs
```

*9.52 ms ± 214 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)*

To conclude running complete code i get ~46ms and running the code in separate segments I get ~10ms!

Why? I am confused!
What can I expect when running the code?

Help appreciated :)

*Python 3.6.3, jupyter notebook 5.0.0*

Comment: I would try using the same `V` in both conditions.

Comment: that was embarrassing! *V was declared multiple times and once differently*. I edited the question and had to change the code a bit to show the problem.